# How to convert XmlElement to Map<XmlAttribute, XmlElement> using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Using JAXB, given the following xml:

```
<MyMap>
    <Entry key="key1" value="value1"/>
    <Entry key="key2" value="value2"/>
</MyMap>
```

I would like to generate the following object structure:

```
class Entry {
    String key;
    String value;
}

public class MyMap {
    Map<String, Entry> entries = new HashMap<>();
}
```

and vice versa.

I am sure that I need to use `XmlAdapter` to convert the collection of `Entry` objects generated by default, into a `Map`. However I'm having difficulty getting the correct solution.

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920634/jaxb-how-to-create-the-xml-element-with-attributes-from-map) which is similar but not quite what I'm after.

Any help is greatly appreciated.